# How to use django_crontab with os.environ['SECRET_KEY']?

Tags: django, cron, python-venv

I'm using a **django_crontab** library and it worked fine until I decided to export my SECRET_KEY to an environmental variable. Summing up what I have done in bash (while in my venv):

```
export SECRET_KEY='some_secret_key_from_settings'
```

In settings.py:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
```

In addition, I use venv, so I've also added this to settings:

```
CRONTAB_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE = '/path_to_my_venv/venv/bin/python3'
```

This is the error that I have:

```
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 681, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'
```

The closest solution I found was this: https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/issues/74

However, I'm not too experienced in this stuff and didn't understand what I should do. I will be very grateful for answers with explicit steps I could take to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using ***environment variables*** isn't a MUST for you, you can use `python-decouple` package which is pretty straightforward and easy to use. see [this](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) at pypi.

then, you can read `SECRET_KEY` like this: (in `settings.py`)

```
    ...
    from decouple import config
    ...

    SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I use https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ to store hidden values. But I suppose that storing in .env implies that SECRET_KEY must be randomly generated somewhere because we don't upload this kind of files to the repository. Or there are ways to keep my existing SECRET_KEY?

Comment: Oh, sorry, we don't upload virtual environment as well. I'm not sure what to do then

Comment: @RV87 You should not push your .env file to VCS. because you store all your sensitive data in it, so you must keep it private. and you don't have to keep the same SECRET_KEY forever, you can change it to anything, anytime you want (until your django app does not using cryptographic signature). use this link for generating SECRET_KEYs: https://djecrety.ir/